# How to calculate the bounding box of a map, given the pixel width/height of the container map & a bounding box which is included in the container map

Tags: extents, mapping

How can I calculate the bounding box of a map, given the pixel width/height of the container map and a bounding box which is included in the container map?

I know how to do this with Google Maps JavaScript API... but I want to do this only with a calculation.

Comment: Can you include more detail, and explain what you have tried so far? I think the title is too long.

Comment: So you have a bounding box, and the pixel dimensions of a map container, and you want a bounding box? Don't you already have it? I think you need to clarify this question.